# Query with parameter

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a query in `Mysql` like the following:

```
SELECT        id, nome, sigla
FROM            pais
WHERE    (estado=@estado)
```

In my code without using the parameter I would simply use:

```
this.cidadeTableAdapter.Fill(this.anfeDataSet1.cidade);
```

and everything would be ok.

More using the parameter how do I put a value on the parameter and pass to the TableAdapter?

Comment: Your original message said you had a query in `Msql` - did you mean MySQL by that, or Microsoft **SQL Server** ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx

```
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("SELECT id, nome, sigla FROM  pais WHERE (estado=@estado)", connection);
com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("estado", value)); 
        SqlDataAdapter cidadeTableAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
        cidadeTableAdapter.SelectCommand = this.com;
        DataSet set = new DataSet("return");
        cidadeTableAdapter.Fill(set);
        this.com.Connection.Close();
        return set;
```

Best option btw is to use the connection to the database so you don't have to close it explicitly.

Comment: I understand what everyone is talking about, the more I want to know is ...
Even creating a query in the TableAdapter's design that I would write this code or is there another way to do it because I did everything by the designer mode

Comment: Explain what you mean by that.. you create the query using the designer mode and then??

Answer (score 0):

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) //create connection
{
        connection.Open();//openconnection

        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT id, nome, sigla FROM  pais
WHERE (estado=@estado)", connection)) //create command
        {

             command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("estado", value)); //add parameter

             SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader(); //execute reader
             while (reader.Read())
             {
                 ...... //read the data
             }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Even creating a query in the TableAdapter's design that I would write this code or is there another way to do it because I did everything by the designer mode

Comment: Create a Command like this, and assign it to a DataAdapter.SelectCommand property

Comment: look here [SqlDataAdapter.SelectCommand Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.selectcommand.aspx)

Comment: created

  SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand ("SELECT id, name, symbol FROM parents WHERE (state = @ state)");
             com.Parameters.Add (new SqlParameter ("state", ufcb.SelectedValue));
             CidadeTableAdapter SqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter ();
             cidadeTableAdapter.SelectCommand = this.com;

get more error in this.com;


Error 1 'aNfe.Empresa' does not contain a definition for 'with' and the extension method 'with' Accepting the first argument of type 'aNfe.Empresa' could be found (...)

Comment: I see this.com, and presume it's kind of global var, try to write com instead.